# Wordpress: Append jquery script for each [partners] shortcode with specified values

Tags: jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to do a shortcode which will add additional jQuery script to `wp_footer`.

So this gonna be an example shortcode:

```
function partners($atts ) {
    global $extra_options, $pslider;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
            'ids' => null,
            'extra_options' => null
        ), $atts));  

    $pslider = 'partners-slider'.rand(100,999);
    $ids = explode( ',', $ids );
    $output = '<div class="section row-one"><div class="col ps-gradient"><div class="ps-wrap"><div class="'.$pslider.'">';
    foreach($ids as $id) {    
    $img_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $output .= '<div class="pslide"><a href="' . $alt_text . '"><img src="' . $img_attr[0] . '" /></a></div>';    
    }
    $output .= '</div></div></div></div>';
    return $output;  
}  

add_shortcode('partners', 'partners');
```

From the above function I need to get variables and place them in a jQuery script:

```
function print_partners_scripts() {
    global $extra_options, $pslider;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
    echo 'jQuery(document).ready( function() {'. "\n";
    echo '  $(".'.$pslider.'").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 1,
        autoStart: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 7,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 5,
        autoHover: true
        ' . $extra_options . '
        });' . "\n";
    echo '});' . "\n";
    echo '</script>' . "\n";
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_partners_scripts' );
```

Ok, at the moment I have a shortcode which can return working slider.

But, what if I try to use this shortcode again on the same page? I've checked, the jQuery script will append only once.

I would like to generate this jQuery script for every [partners] shortcode.

For example:

```
[partners extra_options="something: true"]
[partners extra_options="something: false"]
```

First one should add this script to `wp_footer`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".pslider342").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 1,
        autoStart: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 7,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 5,
        autoHover: true,
        extra_options: true
    });
});
</script>
```

It worked.
The second one should add the same script with different variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        $(".pslider456").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 1,
        autoStart: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 7,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 5,
        autoHover: true,
        extra_options: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately this one was not added.

Really need your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function print_partners_scripts() {
    global $pslider;
    foreach( $pslider as $id => $value ):
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
    echo 'jQuery(document).ready( function() {'. "\n";
    echo '  $(".partners-slider-'.$id.'").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 1,
        autoStart: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 7,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 5,
        autoHover: true,
        ' . $value . '
        });' . "\n";
    echo '});' . "\n";
    echo '</script>' . "\n";
    endforeach;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_partners_scripts' );

function partners($atts ) {
    global $pslider;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
            'ids' => null,
            'extra_options' => null
        ), $atts));  

    $unique_id = uniqid();
    $pslider[$unique_id] = $extra_options;
    $ids = explode( ',', $ids );
    $output = '<div class="section row-one"><div class="col ps-gradient"><div class="ps-wrap"><div class="partners-slider-'.$unique_id.'">';
    foreach($ids as $id) {    
    $img_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $output .= '<div class="pslide"><a href="' . $alt_text . '"><img src="' . $img_attr[0] . '" /></a></div>';    
    }
    $output .= '</div></div></div></div>';
    return $output;  
}  

add_shortcode('partners', 'partners');
```